# Determine a reverse value based on a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a HTML page with a CSS animation that is 'pushing' the main container of the page to the right by 100px when the left-hand nav menu is hovered over.

However, this menu needs to be pushed in decrementally less pixel amounts as the window size increases.

At a browser window size of 790px wide (or less), the container's `left` position is 59px (retrieved using jQuery's `$.offset().left`, and it needs to be pushed by the full 100px to make the menu visible.

However, as the browser window size increases between 790px and 1039px, the menu needs to be pushed less and less - so by the time the window size is 1039px/container's `left` position 184px, the push needs to only be 1px.

So the **window size range** I am working with is:

```
1039 - 790 = 249px
```

The **position range of the container** adjusts in those window sizes to:

```
183 (when window size is 1039) - 59 (when window size is 790) = 124px
```

I want to **push the menu** like this:

```
min container position: left 59px = 100px push
max container position: left 183px = 1px push
```

*and* between 1px and 100px for the values between the the min and max container position.

How can I assign a push value of 100px when the window size is 790px/or the container's left position is 59px, and assign a decreasing range of push values when the window size/left position increases?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jazzbangle/5mn3y29k/4/

Comment: Use media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries or use `resize()` in jquery

Comment: I'm using media queries to make the menu be fully visible with no push animation when the window size is 1039px+. However, between 1039px and 790px, the menu needs to be pushed in varying amounts. I can't use media queries to do this unless I add a hundred of them to account for the 100px push. As far as I can tell, the jquery `resize()` function just fires when the window resizes - I still need to be able to determine how many pixels to push the menu out based on the container position.

Comment: You can use transitions with media queries

Comment: can you put together a jsfiddle example please, I think this can be fixed by getting away from fixed pixel sizes, but I'd need to visualise it properly in order to answer that

Comment: @ToniLeigh jsfiddle set up here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jazzbangle/5mn3y29k/4/

Just to clarify, the content container (container2) is being animated within the main container (container, which has `overflow:hidden`) to avoid horizontal scrollbars appearing on smaller screens when the menu pushes out. However, less of container2 needs to be pushed out as the window width increases.